# anyway to improve the performance of query or any alternate way

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

i have storedprocedure where i want to optimise the query. i need to set data for three different types in same temp table. below is my query

```
SET @Counter = -3;      
WHILE (@Counter <=-1)      
 BEGIN    
 insert into #tempTable (col1, col2,amount)
 select col1,col2,
  CASE 
      WHEN @Counter  = -2 THEN MAX(col3) --sample actual is different
      WHEN @Counter  = -3 then sum(Col3)
      WHEN @Counter  = -1 col3
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;      
      from   #tempTable where amount>100 
      group by col1,col2,amount
END
```

any way to optimise it

Comment: Please close your `CASE`.

Comment: Not using a loop would be a good place to start.

Comment: Your query has several problems. It won't run as it is. It would be better if you also explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I would also ask how you plan on knowing which row is which value. The sum, max and even the value in some cases can be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `UNION ALL` ? :

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable (col1, col2, amount)
     SELECT col1, col2, MAX(col3)
     FROM #tempTable 
     WHERE amount > 100
     GROUP BY col1, col2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3)
     FROM #tempTable 
     WHERE amount > 100
     GROUP BY col1, col2 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT col1, col2, col3
     FROM #tempTable 
     WHERE amount > 100;
```

Comment: @LuisCazares. . .  This is alternative way where OP can avoid `loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculated the result for amount and then use a left join.

```
SET @Counter = -3;      
WHILE (@Counter <=-1)      
BEGIN    
    insert into #tempTable (col1, col2,amount)
    select 
        t1.col1, t1.col2,
        CASE 
            WHEN @Counter  = -2 THEN t1.MAX_COL3 
            WHEN @Counter  = -3 then t2.SUM_COL3
            WHEN @Counter  = -1 THEN t1.col3
        END AS amount
        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;      
    FROM  #tempTable t1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            col1, col2, 
            MAX(BillRate) AS MAX_COL3, 
            SUM(BillRate) AS SUM_COL3
        FROM #tempTable 
        GROUP BY col1, col2
    ) t2
        ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
        AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
    WHERE AMOUNT > 100 
END
```